# Best way to store text in elasticsearch that does not need to be search, analyzed or aggregatable?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

What is better solution for storing just a text in elasticsearch 5.x for a text field no longer then 256 characters, when this field does NOT need to be:

- searchable
- indexed
- analyzed
- sortable...

Option 1)
Set mapping to **text** with index=false

Option 2)
Set mapping to **keyword** with index=false, doc_values=false

What is more space efficient? Or what is the difference between these two mappings whit these settings?

Thank you.

Comment: Go with 1st option, keyword is used for exact phrase matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely use the `keyword` type so your text is not analyzed (as if it was a `text` field).

In addition to the settings you mentioned, I'd set a few more parameters, such as the [`ignore_above`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-above.html) and [`include_in_all`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/include-in-all.html).

So:

```
    "field_name": {
      "type":  "keyword",
      "index": false,
      "doc_values": false,
      "ignore_above": 256,
      "include_in_all": false
    }
```